# Order index for rows related to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that stores an id from another table, an index for a specific id and some different value

| user_id | index_value | some_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 01 |
| 1 | 1 | 02 |
| 1 | 2 | 03 |
| 2 | 0 | 04 |
| 3 | 0 | 05 |
| 3 | 1 | 06 |
| 1 | 3 | 07 |

I'm about to delete some records and I need to recalculate the data stored in index_value. For example, delete the line with some_value 03.The expected output should look like this:

| user_id | index_value | some_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 01 |
| 1 | 1 | 02 |
| 2 | 0 | 04 |
| 3 | 0 | 05 |
| 3 | 1 | 06 |
| 1 | **2** | **07** |

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: *The expected output should look like this* You need to retrieve shown output from SELECT query or you need to recalculate the data stored in the table? These are two absolutely different tasks.

Comment: @Akina I need to recalculate the data stored in the table. Thanks for noticing

Comment: "I need to recalculate the data stored in the table"- how did you do that in the first place? What keeps you from using an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: *I need to recalculate the data stored in the table.* If so then you need in 2 queries (maybe within one stored procedure). First deletes the row, second updates the table. Use  the query provided in Tim's answer as a datasource for an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used suggestions from Tim Biegeleisen and Akina.
After recalculating the indexes, a query is called to remove unnecessary rows.

```
UPDATE table AS t
SET index_value =
    (SELECT new_index_value 
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY index_value) - 1 AS new_index_value 
        FROM table WHERE user_id IN (
            SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE some_value='some value'
            GROUP BY user_id)
        AND NOT some_value='some value'
        ORDER BY ID)
    WHERE ID = t.ID
)
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE some_value='some value'
    GROUP BY user_id)
AND NOT some_value='some value';
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not even maintaining the `index_value` column, but instead generating this computed value at the time you query.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY some_value) - 1 AS index_value,
    some_value
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY some_value;
```